# Flutter TextField TextFieldController setState - position of cursor changes

Tags: flutter, textfield, setstate

I recently wrote a test program that I needed that is essentially a CRUD program. I needed to handle this differently to other similar programs that I have written, because I normally use a stateful FAB widget, and don't have to setState() to enable and disable the FAB. In this test program I didn't want to use the custom FAB, and used the standard FAB. I found that whenever I had to enable or disable the FAB because of a change to a TextField, that this required a setState(), and after the build, the cursor for the TextField that was being edited had repositioned. I don't know why that happens, because I had not recreated the Widgets. The only solution that I could come up with to handle that issue was fairly messy and required saving the Widget position in the List of TextField and also save the Selection, and then after the build resetting the Selection to the saved Selection.

What I need to achieve is for the FAB to be only enabled when data has changed. Obviously this can vary with every key entry.

I presume I'm not handling this in the optimal way. How is this handled so that the cursor position remains as it was prior to the build?

----- Have Now Added Code below ----

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

//=====================================================================================

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test Widgets',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(title: 'Test Widgets'),
    );
  }
}

//=====================================================================================

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

//=====================================================================================

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool _tfDataHasChanged = false;
  bool _tfInitialized = false;
  bool _tfSaveSelection = false;
  int _iNdxWidgetChanged = -1;
  List<String> _lsOldData = ['Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3', 'Row 4'];
  List<String> _lsNewData = ['Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3', 'Row 4'];
  List<TextField> _lwTextFields;
  TextSelection _wTextSelection;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (int iNdxWidget = 0;
        _lwTextFields != null && iNdxWidget < _lwTextFields.length;
        iNdxWidget++) {
      _lwTextFields[iNdxWidget].focusNode.removeListener(() {
        _fnFocusChanged();
      });
      _lwTextFields[iNdxWidget]?.controller?.dispose();
      _lwTextFields[iNdxWidget]?.focusNode?.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _tfInitialized = false;
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _fnOnBuildComplete());
    if (_lwTextFields == null) {
      _fnCreateAllWidgets();
    }
    List<Widget> lwDisplay = _fnCreateDisplay();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
        child: _fnCreateAppBarWidgets(),
      )),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: lwDisplay,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _tfDataHasChanged ? _fnUpdateData : null,
        tooltip: 'Update',
        backgroundColor: _tfDataHasChanged ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
        child: Icon(Icons.done),
      ),
    );
  }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  _fnOnBuildComplete() {
    _tfInitialized = true;
    if (_tfSaveSelection && _iNdxWidgetChanged >= 0) {
      _lwTextFields[_iNdxWidgetChanged].controller.selection = _wTextSelection;
    }
  }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  void _fnCreateAllWidgets() {
    _lwTextFields = List(_lsNewData.length);
    for (int iNdxWidget = 0; iNdxWidget < _lwTextFields.length; iNdxWidget++) {
      _fnCreateTextField(iNdxWidget);
    }
  }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  void _fnCreateTextField(int iNdxWidget) {
    TextEditingController wController = TextEditingController();

    FocusNode wFocusNode = FocusNode();
    wFocusNode.addListener(() => _fnFocusChanged());

    _lwTextFields[iNdxWidget] = TextField(
      autofocus: false, //(iNdxWidget == 0),
      autocorrect: false,
      enabled: true,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      maxLength: 25,
      controller: wController,
      focusNode: wFocusNode,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next /* TYPE OF ACTION KEY */,
      onSubmitted: ((v) => _fnSetNextFocus(iNdxWidget)),
      onChanged: (text) => _fnTextListener(iNdxWidget, text),
      decoration: _fnCreateInputDecoration(
          'Text Field Number ${iNdxWidget + 1}', 'Enter Data'),
      style: _fnCreateWidgetTextStyle(Colors.blue[700]),
    );
  }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  _fnTextListener(int iNdxWidget, String sText) {
    if (_tfInitialized) {
      _lsNewData[iNdxWidget] = sText;
      _fnCheckIfDataHasChanged(
          iNdxWidget) /* ENABLE OR DISABLE SUBMIT BUTTON */;
    }
  }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  _fnSetNextFocus(int iNdxWidget) {
    if (_lwTextFields[iNdxWidget].focusNode.hasFocus) {
      _lwTextFields[iNdxWidget].focusNode.unfocus();
      if (iNdxWidget + 1 < _lwTextFields.length) {
        _lwTextFields[iNdxWidget + 1]?.focusNode?.requestFocus();
      }
    }
  }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  InputDecoration _fnCreateInputDecoration(String sHeading, String sHint) {
    return InputDecoration(
      labelText: sHeading,
      hintText: sHint,
      border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
    );
  }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  TextStyle _fnCreateWidgetTextStyle(Color color) {
    return TextStyle(
      fontSize: 14.0,
      color: color,
    );
  }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  List<Widget> _fnCreateDisplay() {
    List<Widget> lwDisplay = List((_lwTextFields.length * 2) + 2);
    lwDisplay[0] = SizedBox(height: 10);
    int iNdxDisplay = 1;
    for (int iNdxWidget = 0; iNdxWidget < _lwTextFields.length; iNdxWidget++) {
      _lwTextFields[iNdxWidget].controller.text = _lsNewData[iNdxWidget];
      lwDisplay[iNdxDisplay++] = _lwTextFields[iNdxWidget];
      lwDisplay[iNdxDisplay++] =
          SizedBox(height: iNdxDisplay < lwDisplay.length - 2 ? 10 : 80);
    }
    lwDisplay[lwDisplay.length - 1] = Divider(color: Colors.black, height: 2);
    return lwDisplay;
  }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  _fnUpdateData() {
    for (int iNdxWidget = 0; iNdxWidget < _lsNewData.length; iNdxWidget++) {
      if (_lsNewData[iNdxWidget] != _lsOldData[iNdxWidget]) {
        _lsOldData[iNdxWidget] = _lsNewData[iNdxWidget];
      }
    }
    _fnCheckIfDataHasChanged(-1);
  }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  _fnCheckIfDataHasChanged(int iNdxWidgetChanged) {
    bool tfChanged = false /* INIT */;
    for (int iNdxWidgetTest = 0;
        !tfChanged && iNdxWidgetTest < _lsNewData.length;
        iNdxWidgetTest++) {
      tfChanged = _lsNewData[iNdxWidgetTest] != _lsOldData[iNdxWidgetTest];
    }
    if (iNdxWidgetChanged >= 0) {
      _iNdxWidgetChanged = iNdxWidgetChanged;
      _wTextSelection = _lwTextFields[iNdxWidgetChanged].controller.selection;
    }
    if (tfChanged != _tfDataHasChanged) {
      setState(() => _tfDataHasChanged = tfChanged) /* WE NEED TO ENABLE FAB */;
    }
  }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Row _fnCreateAppBarWidgets() {
    IconData wIconData =
        _tfSaveSelection ? Icons.check_box : Icons.check_box_outline_blank;
    Color wColor = _tfSaveSelection ? Colors.blue[900] : Colors.grey[600];
    IconButton wIconButton = IconButton(
        icon: Icon(wIconData),
        color: wColor,
        onPressed: _fnCheckboxChanged,
        iconSize: 40);
    return Row(children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(width: 10),
      Text('Save\nSelection', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
      wIconButton,
      SizedBox(width: 30),
      Text('Test TextField')
    ]);
  }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  _fnFocusChanged() {
    for (int iNdxWidget = 0; iNdxWidget < _lwTextFields.length; iNdxWidget++) {
      if (_lwTextFields[iNdxWidget].focusNode.hasFocus) {
        _iNdxWidgetChanged = iNdxWidget;
        _wTextSelection = _lwTextFields[iNdxWidget].controller.selection;
        return;
      }
    }
  }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  void _fnCheckboxChanged() {
    _tfSaveSelection = !_tfSaveSelection;
    if (!_tfSaveSelection) {
      _iNdxWidgetChanged = -1;
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

-------- Have added key to TextField, but issue persists ---------

```
  key: ValueKey<int>(iNdxWidget),
```

Comment: post your code: normally `TextField` keeps track the cursor position so it does not change

Comment: @pskink. Have added code to post.

Comment: @pskink I added the key, but issue persists.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8QnRn7wXmb/

Comment: @pskink After more testing, I have discovered that the problem appears to be that Flutter "misbehaves" when there is more than one reference to a Widget. I hope this is a bug in Flutter, because I make copies as in this test program in lots of places because many of my programs are parameterized.

Comment: more than one reference? what you mean by that? did you run the code I posted?

Comment: Yes, I presume it is similar to another program I wrote. If you look at the initial program in my question, I make a copy of the Widgets because I build another List of Widgets that I use in the display, because I add some screen formatting. This list is temporary (local). However, by creating another reference to the Widgets apparently causes the problem with Flutter for some reason unknown to me. Without making that copy, the problem goes away. However, I need to make that copy because of the way the programs are written. I hope that is more clear.

Comment: so post the minimal code that has the problem you have (just like my 37 lines of code) - basically I have no idea what local list you mean

Comment: Needs more testing because results are inconsistent. In the program that I posted in the initial question, there are 2 lists of widgets. 1, A global list of TextFields (_lwTextFields), and 2, a local non-global list used in "build" that is solely used for the display in "build" (lwDisplay). When I alter that original program and solely use the list of TextFields, I do not get the problem, so  I presumed that the problem revolved around having multiple references to the TextFields. However, I just created another minimal test program using the 2 lists but this works OK (cursor positioning).

Comment: here you have the same "2 list" version: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fHkKh6pBqT/ - but honestly the way you are caching widgets is wrong: see [Flutter: Don’t Fear the Garbage Collector](https://medium.com/flutter/flutter-dont-fear-the-garbage-collector-d69b3ff1ca30) - they say: *"It’s not uncommon to see new Flutter developers create references to widgets they know will not change over time, and place them in state so that they won’t be destroyed and rebuilt.
Don’t do this."*

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll look at that. But, I don't think what I am doing should break Flutter. I've posted a bug, so I'll see what they say - if and when they get to it.

Comment: i have really no idea why do you want your code so complex, why two lists and copying its content again and again? why `SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(`? compare it with those 58 [lines of code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bGNfhnWmM8/) that do exactly what you want

Comment: Yes, but this is just a test program to reproduce what appears to be a bug in a much larger program. All I'm copying are references. The fact that it works in one program and not another appears to me to highlight a bug. Whether or not what I'm doing is sane or not, if it should work, then it needs to be resolved. This is not an exercise to write the smallest code, it's an exercise to attempt to reproduce what appears to me to be a bug. In a smaller program the same logic works for me. In a larger program it does not. Lets see what they say - if and when they get to it.

Comment: so change this line: `TextEditingController wController = TextEditingController(text: _lsNewData[iNdxWidget]);` and remove this one 

      `_lwTextFields[iNdxWidget].controller.text = _lsNewData[iNdxWidget];`

Comment: Well, thanks for solving that problem. I'll delete the bug post. I should have noticed that!!! Why don't you post the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bug - as posted by @pskink

My excuse - I normally use a stateful FAB, so I don't normally encounter this.

Answer:
so change this line:

```
TextEditingController wController = TextEditingController(text: _lsNewData[iNdxWidget]);
```

and remove this one

```
_lwTextFields[iNdxWidget].controller.text = _lsNewData[iNdxWidget];
```

– pskink Feb 23 at 7:33

Answer (score 0):

I hope these functions might help you

```
  void updateText(String text) {
    if (text != null) {
      this.text = _applyMask(mask, text);
    } else {
      this.text = '';
    }

    _lastUpdatedText = this.text;
  }

  void updateMask(String mask, {bool moveCursorToEnd = true}) {
    this.mask = mask;
    updateText(text);

    if (moveCursorToEnd) {
      this.moveCursorToEnd();
    }
  }

  void moveCursorToEnd() {
    final String text = _lastUpdatedText;
    selection =
        TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: (text ?? '').length));
  }
```